# How to create Ambari database backup without enter password?

Tags: linux, postgresql

We've configured the file `.pgpass` as the following and in order to create database backups without to enter a password

```
-bash-4.2$ more .pgpass
localhost:5432:postgres:ambari:bigdata
-bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql
-bash-4.2$ whoami
postgres
-bash-4.2$ more .pgpass
localhost:5432:postgres:ambari:bigdata
-bash-4.2$
```

After that `pg_dump` still insist to enter the password - why?

Where I am wrong?

```
pg_dump -U  ambari  -f ambari.sql
Password:
```

Comment: what are the permissions on your `.pgpass` file?  The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/libpq-pgpass.html) says *On Unix systems, the permissions on .pgpass must disallow any access to world or group; achieve this by the command `chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass`. **If the permissions are less strict than this, the file will be ignored**. On Microsoft Windows, it is assumed that the file is stored in a directory that is secure, so no special permissions check is made.*

Comment: @cas, right. This was also discussed under https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893979/6771046.